# Implementing Blur effects in iCarousel -iOS7/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, highcharts, ios7, blur

I have an iCarousel of many items showing high-charts like bubble chart, pie chart and more. I want to include blur effects for charts when a chart is not in the current item index. When i tried to include blur effects my carousel is not smooth at all and makes scrolling very slow.

What should i do for solving this issue.

Comment: You should include a faster blur effect.

Comment: Any link or sample codes you know for faster blur effect.

Comment: How can I say that any code is faster if I didn't see your code ?

Comment: ILTranslucentView *translucentView = [[ILTranslucentView alloc]initWithFrame:self.carousel.currentItemView.frame];
    [carousel.currentItemView addSubview:translucentView];
    translucentView.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
    
    //optional:
    translucentView.translucentAlpha = 0.2;
    translucentView.translucentStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    translucentView.translucentTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    translucentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: Please edit your question, the code is not readable at comments. I also have no idea what `ILTranslucentView ` is.